# Is there a way to generate hashes for my rollup bundles and inject them into the resulting HTML's CSP meta tag?

Tags: html, hash, content-security-policy, webassembly, rollupjs

I'm writing a single-page app in Rust and bundling it with rollup, which works great.

The problem is that currently I need to enable `unsafe-eval` for `script-src` for my WASM to be loaded on chromium and webkit-based browsers (not Firefox for some reason).

I plan to ship my app in two different forms:

- A native wrapper using the excellent [web-view](https://github.com/Boscop/web-view), where the bundled JS is inlined into the HTML and the resulting fat HTML file is embedded into the wrapper binary (I'd say in this case enabling `unsafe-eval` and/or `unsafe-inline` is less of an issue because if something can inject code into my native wrapper the user is screwed anyway)
- A static website hosted on Github pages or Netlify where the JS, WASM and CSS aren't inlined (I'd say traditional XSS is more of of a potential issue here)

The best solution I can come up with is to hash all the {JS, WASM, CSS} files that rollup outputs at bundle time, and then inject the hashes into the HTML's `Content-Security-Policy` `meta` tag.

My question is, is there a way to do what I described that doesn't require me to write a rollup plugin?
I've tried searching on Github, Duckduckgo and NPM but found nothing of interest, so if anyone has a way to do the above (or a better solution for this issue) it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found this plugin for webpack: https://github.com/slackhq/csp-html-webpack-plugin

But I remember having issues inlining the WASM from wasm-pack using webpack so I'm probably not going to use it.